# Python: Multiline input converted into a list

Tags: python, list, input, python-3.x, multiline

I have a programming assignment and all of the inputs that I need to enter are multilined.
For example:

```
4 3
10 3
100 5
1000000000 8
```

or:

```
7 8 666
8 7 666
10 16 273
```

I am trying to convert the lines into lists. I can't use files and I need to be able to input them into the program using an input statement.

The problem I am having is, I want the output to be:

```
[['4', '3'], ['10', '3'], ['100', '5'], ['1000000000', '8']]
```

so I can use it to finish the rest of my program. But what I am getting is only:

```
[['4', '3']]
```

The code I have been trying to use is:

```
aString = input(" > ")
aString_list = [x for x in (y.split() for y in aString.split('\n')) if x]
print(aString_list)
```

I am confused on how to get it to read the other lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `input()` stops as soon as you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, to get continuous  input you need to use a either a `while` loop or a `for` loop and take input until user enters a sentinel value:

Using for-loop and `iter`:

```
def multiline_input(sentinel=''):
    for inp in iter(input, sentinel):
        yield inp.split()
...         
>>> lis = list(multiline_input())
1 2 3
400 500 600
a b c

>>> lis
[['1', '2', '3'], ['400', '500', '600'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Using `while` loop:

```
def multiline_input(sentinel=''):
    while True:
        inp = input()
        if inp != sentinel:
            yield inp.split()
        else:
            break
...             
>>> lis = list(multiline_input())
1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8 9
10

>>> lis
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9'], ['10']]
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be something I do not understand, but in the performance of such code here

```
aString = """
4 3
10 3
100 5
1000000000 8
"""

aString_list = [x for x in (y.split() for y in aString.split('\n')) if x]
print(aString_list)
```

we get a result:

```
[['4', '3'], ['10', '3'], ['100', '5'], ['1000000000', '8']]
```